# I purchased a motorcycle that has not been delivered, how can I resolve this with the company?

Tags: auto-loan, refund, north-carolina

I purchased a motorcycle from Blue Ridge HD in Hickory, NC, almost 2 months ago on 3/30/21. I still don't have the bike.

Conditions of the sale was that the dealership get the gas tank vinyl wrapped, and this was supposed to take 2 weeks max. Every week after the first 2 weeks, the sales manager I dealt with promised that the bike would be ready the next week for certain.

I am tired of being lied to by them, and I am looking for options on how to get this resolved. I have contacted HD Corporate Customer Support and have left a complaint with the BBB.

However, none of that seems to phase the dealership. Any ideas on how to get the ball rolling and get the bike? Any chance of me getting a refund? The bike itself has never been in my possession and has never left the dealership. The vinyl wrap job was also subcontracted to a local company.

Comment: Did you pay cash/check  or credit card ? What paperwork did you sign?

Comment: Took out a loan and made the down payment via debit card, have also made a couple payments via debit card. Signed the dealers purchase agreement and signed off on the loan

Comment: Dud you tell them yiu wanted your money back, no matter when the bike would be ready? What did they say?

Comment: When I mentioned a refund, they gave me the run around.

Comment: This sounds more like a question for a legal expert rather than financial advice. What will likely come into play is what was actually written into your purchase agreement. If the "conditions of the sale" don't actually include a delivery date, it gets quite a bit harder. If the vinyl wrap is outsourced, it gets trickier.

Answer (score 4):

In the United States the licensing and regulation of automobile dealerships is done at the state level. In your case (North Carolina) this is done by the [N.C. Division of Motor Vehicles License & Theft Bureau](https://www.dmv.org/nc-north-carolina/buy-sell/car-dealers/dealer-related-information.php)

> Inspectors also enforce the rules and regulations governing:
>
> ```
> Vehicle dealers
> Vehicle safety and emissions inspection stations
> ​Vehicle repair businesses
> ```

You can even [file a complaint via their portal](https://www.ncdot.gov/dmv/programs/fraud-theft/Pages/complaints.aspx):

> The License & Theft Bureau accepts complaints against businesses
> including auto dealerships, inspection stations, repair shops/garages,
> metal recyclers (scrap yards), wrecker/towing facilities, and any
> other company that may be involved in fraudulent or questionable
> activities.
>
> The bureau also accepts complaints against individuals who might be
> involved in wrongdoings such as title fraud, curbstoning (sale of
> vehicles for profit without being licensed as a dealership), odometer
> fraud, identity theft related to driver licenses, and various other
> misdeeds.

I have no experience doing this, but the state website is a place to start.

Answer (score 0):

See if there is a local law firm that offers a free consultation and has experience suing auto dealerships.